# How to list strings that are not found in a folder using unix

Tags: perl, unix

I have a list of strings in a text file . The source folder has some files which contains the string. If a string is found in the source folder, I am copying it to a target folder.

**srcdirectory** - source directory to check if the strings are present.
**stringList.txt** - list of strings to test.
**target** - copy found strings to this folder.

For example,
**srcdirectory** has files :

```
a.edi (contains string 'a' in the content of the file)                                                                                      
b.edi (contains string 'b' in the content of the file)                   
c.edi (contains string 'c' in the content of the file)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
d.edi (contains string 'd' in the content of the file)                        
e.edi (contains string 'e' in the content of the file)   
f.edi (contains string 'f' in the content of the file) 
g.edi (contains string 'g' in the content of the file
```

**stringList.txt** has strings:

```
a              
b      
c           
d           
e
f
g
```

If a match is found for the string, it copies the matched file name to the target folder. So **target** folder contains matched filenames as:

```
 a.edi            
 c.edi           
 g.edi
```

Now, I want the unmatched string list to be copied to a different folder as the one below. How do I do that?

```
    b
    d
    e
    f
```

**Here is my script for matched string:**

```
find srcdirectory/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep -Ril -f stringList.txt {} \; -exec cp -i {} /home/Rose/target \;
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the strings that are not found to a different directory"? Are you writing the strings that are not found into a file in a different directory?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: No, your `find` expression copies _files_, not strings. Please clarify.

Comment: It copes files(with contained strings) into a directory. But I am looking to copy strings which are not found in the files.

Comment: `target - copy found strings to this folder.`: I think you want to copy (or move) files with the strings to the folder. Or do you want to make a txt-file with the strings that have a match? 
In the current requirements all strings in the file stringList.txt will be found: stringList.txt is one one the files where grep looks.

Comment: I want to copy strings that are not found in the files. Please have a look at my question. I have explained with an example.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can do an inverse operation in `find` with the `-o` operator:

```
find srcdirectory -maxdepth 2 -type f \( \
    -exec grep -qif stringList.txt {} \; -exec cp -i {} /home/Rani/target \; \
     \) -o -exec cp -i {} /home/Rani/nonmatches \;
```

The trick here is that the parenthesized expression has to be "true" (success/0 exit status) for files that match, and false otherwise. If the cp -i can fail for matched files, this will be imprecise. If that's a possibility you're concerned about, you would need to capture the status of grep -q and re-apply it after the cp expression.

Perhaps it's just easier to drop into bash.

```
find srcdirectory -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c '
    for file; do
        if grep -qif stringList.txt "$file"; then
            cp -i "$file" /home/Rani/target
        else
            cp -i "$file" /home/Rani/nonmatches
        fi
    done
' _ {} +
```

Comment: I don't want the file which doesn't match with the Strings. I just want the string list which doesn't have any match or file name to be copied to a different folder.